# IF / OR statement causes Call to undefined function() error. Why?

Tags: php, if-statement, undefined-function

I have seen this error message a few times and even after googling quite some time I'm really unable to figure out what is wrong:

```
$uid = GNGHelper::getLoggedInUserID();
$assignedGuideID = $tour->get('guide')->get('juser_id');
$isCoord = GNGHelper::isLoggedInUserCoord();

if (($uid == $assignedGuideID) || ($isCoord === true)) {}
```

I get the following error pointing to the if statement:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function  () in /home/gonative/public_html/dev/modules/mod_gngtourdetails/mod_gngtourdetails.php on line 51

What is wrong with this if statement?

Thanks a lot!
W.

Comment: Are you sure it's that line?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that if statement but note you don't need the extra parens, you can just do `if ($uid == $assignedGuideID || $isCoord === true)`.

Comment: The error message is missing the function's name you are trying to call. Did you remove it? If not, only thing I can imagine is some magic code where you return a closure or something, work with magic methods or assign a function to a variable in combination with magic. Avoid magic in PHP if you are uncertain.

Comment: Responding to your comments: (1) At least the error message points to the if line, that is for sure. (2) Interestingly if I remove the internal brackets, my editor (Aptana Studio) marks a syntax error. (3)  No I haven't removed anything. This IS the exact error message. As far as I'm aware I'm not using any magic PHP, I'm not even aware of what that is. Any other hints?

Comment: nothing on the far right of the line? no hidden characters?

Comment: @Kaddath: Thanks! You got it!!! I removed all extra spaces from the line everywhere and now it works. I still don't understand why, but at least it works. This is my corrected line: `if(($uid == $assignedGuideID)||($isCoord === true)){`

Comment: if there were a hidden character before a `(` and PHP detected it, it was understood as a function call. Another reason why we should be careful with copy/paste!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kaddath: Thanks! You got it!!! I removed all extra spaces from the line everywhere and now it works. I still don't understand why, but at least it works. This is my corrected line: `if(($uid == $assignedGuideID)||($isCoord === true)){` – wanderlusted 17 hours ago
1
if there were a hidden character before a ( and PHP detected it, it was understood as a function call. Another reason why we should be careful with copy/paste!! – Kaddath 2 hours ago